# How to filter unwanted rows in view from a table in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table and one of the columns is status. Values of status are 'Open', 'Closed', 'Verified' and 'Rejected'.
How to write a filter in ng-repeat, so that rows whose status is 'Closed' should not be displayed.

Comment: What does your data look like? A filter would operate on the data, not on the view

Answer (score 3):

You should post some code of what you tried. Anyways...

```
ng-repeat="row in data | filter:{ Status: '!Closed' }"
```

Here's a jsFiddle show casing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/62za0fs7/

Comment: I have already a filter to sort the according to the status like this. <tr data-ng-repeat="userDetails in data |filter:status:status.statusName" > How to put the filter if the status is closed?

Answer (score -2):

```
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

    <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <table id="searchTextResults">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what question asks and neither does it give any explanation for code you posted

Comment: This is copied directly from the angular site and doesn't help.

Comment: as per my understanding i will post